# Shorewall - One external IP for two hosts with nginx and keepalived

Tags: firewall, shorewall

I'm following this tutorial to setup keepalived: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/keepalived-basics

It requires two hosts to share one external IP, where the second host is the failover.

I'm unsure how to go about this, and I have been searching for a good while, without success.
I've come with this idea in `/etc/shorewall/nat`, but I'm sure it'll mess things up:

```
# proxy1
1.2.3.4    eth0    192.168.0.10    No    No
# proxy2
1.2.3.4    eth0    192.168.0.11    No    No
```

And then have these rules:

```
# proxy1
Web/DNAT    net    dmz:192.168.0.10    - - - 1.2.3.4
# proxy2
Web/DNAT    net    dmz:192.168.0.11    - - - 1.2.3.4
```

I have done no testing as we have no testing environment for firewall configurations, so changes are generally risky. `shorewall check` does not show any errors with this.

Will this work or completely mess up web traffic? If it doesn't work, how should I otherwise solve this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of this Shorewall configuration, then? It doesn't seem at all related to the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The tutorial is there for context, I should have been clear; sorry about that. The question is simply, how do I share one external IP between two hosts? We usually just masquerade one external IP to a single internal IP, which is done by shorewall. This time we need to have to internal IPs share one external IP, where one of the internals are a fail over.

Comment: You NAT to _one_ internal IP, the one that is shared between the two hosts.